# How to get contents of file in Sublime Text 3 Python API

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm very new to Python and Sublime Text API dev... so this may be easy?

I want to display the contents of a file (that sits next to the currently open file) to a new panel window.

I can create a new panel no problem and get it to display a string using

```
def newLogWindow(self, output):
    window = self.view.window()

    new_view = window.create_output_panel("log")
    new_view.run_command('erase_view')
    new_view.run_command('append', {'characters': output})
    window.run_command("show_panel", {"panel": "output.log"})

    sublime.status_message('Metalang')

pass
```

But what I need is a function to get contents of file to pass to that function.

```
content = xxxx.open_file("filename.txt")
// somehow get contents of this file?
// pass it to log window
self.newLogWindow(content);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sublime Text, the built in API to open a file is tied to the `Window` and will return a `View` that corresponds to a tab. In your case, you want to update a panel (an existing `View` that doesn't relate to a tab) with the contents of the file, so the Sublime Text API can't be used for this.

Instead you can do it directly in Python using the [`open` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    content = myfile.read()
    self.newLogWindow(content)
```

Comment: Thanks for that @keith-hall.. "Works" except for all the NUL's I can see in the output -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/iepdg00pobmshp6/Capture.PNG?raw=1. Any idea how to get rid of those?

Comment: @markstewie what encoding was your `filename.txt` saved with? you may need to specify it as part of the `open` call - `open('filename.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')` for example.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't work but definitely something to do with encoding... I've copied contents of real file to new test file and works as expected. So I need to work out how to change content type of file..

Comment: Found out the file encoding of the log file I'm trying to read is utf16be

Comment: @markstewie then I think it should work with `encoding='utf-16be'`

Comment: Just using `encoding='utf-16' did the job! Thanks for your help @keith-hall